# Scrolling not working on list of data - ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have displayed a list of 10 items on to my app using `<ion-list>`. However, when i use `ion-scroll` with height to make it scrollable, the list get stuck on the 5 item, i am not able to scroll to the bottom of the items displayed.

What could be the issue here ?

*View**

```
<ion-content   padding>
        <ion-scroll style="height: 500px;" >
        <ion-list  *ngFor=" let items of mydata" class="sec-list" no-margin>
    <div *ngIf="mydata?.length > 0">
    <ion-item">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{items.img}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>     
    </ion-item>

        </div>
  </ion-list> 
</ion-scroll>
  <ion-footer>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-col text-center>
          <button  ion-button class="add-report" block>
             Click Here
            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-item> 
      </ion-footer>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- According to documentation of ionic V3 for [ion-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/scroll/Scroll/), you have to specify the scroll direction.

like this one. 

`<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
    content goes here...
</ion-scroll>`

2- You may use css property **overflow: auto** to scroll a list of item in a container like **div**.